# How do Python methods handle arbitrary parameters?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I will use the `range` function as the main example in this question.

I use `range` a lot to generate a list of numbers. However, I use it often with different parameters, specifically a different NUMBER of parameters. It makes me wonder how `range` easily handles different numbers of parameters and assigns them to their respective value (if they represent the highest value, or the smallest value, or the interval between values). How does `range` do this? Does it use `if` statements to handle each scenario, or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: those are handled using *args and **kwargs, which are dynamic parameters which need not be used. but if used the function will have the intelligence to take that parameter. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs and http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to handle a variable number of arguments, you can provide default parameters:
Note: range is not implement this way but is just here for illustration:

```
def my_range(start=0, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop == None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step
```

Now you can call this:

```
list(my_range(10))          # 0..9
list(my_range(2, 10))       # 2..9
list(my_range(10, step=2))  # 0,2,4,6,8
```

The other way is to use `*` for unnamed args and `**` for keyword args, the above implemented with `*args` and `**kwargs` is a lot messier.

```
def my_range(*args, **kwargs):
    d = {'start':0, 'stop':None, 'step':1}
    for arg, v in zip(('start', 'stop', 'step'), args):
         d[arg] = v
    d.update(kwargs)
    start, stop, step = (d[arg] for arg in ('start', 'stop', 'step'))
    if stop == None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step
```

Obviously the former is much easier to implement, and the latter is usually reserved for special cases and would not be used to implement the above.

Answer (score 2):

At a higher level Python lets you define your functions as:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

This form of abstract definition enables any number of arguments. The implementation then is the developer's choice. The range function prototype is:

```
 range(start, stop[, step])
```

to mean start and stop are expected and step is optional. However, the implementation of this allows for an alternate prototype

```
 range(stop)
```

where start defaults to 0 and step defaults to 1. The only thing that makes range look like an overloaded function is its ability to accept an implicit 0 value for start although it is the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Python functions [allow a variable number of arguments](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions), either with default argument values:

```
def range(start, stop=None, step=None):
     if stop is None:
         start = 0
         stop = start
     if step is None:
         step = 1

     while (step > 0 and start < stop) or (step < 0 and start > stop):
         yield start
         start += step
```

(This is not a complete implementation of all the semantics of range). Alternatively, use [`*args` and `**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters):

```
def range(*args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) == 1:
        start = 0
        stop = args[0]
        step = 1
    elif len(args) == 2:
        start, stop = args
        step = 1
    elif len(args) == 3:
        start, stop, step = args

    if 'start' in kwargs:
        start = kwargs['start']
    if 'stop' in kwargs:
        stop = kwargs['stop']
    if 'step' in kwargs:
        step = kwargs['step']

     while (step > 0 and start < stop) or (step < 0 and start > stop):
         yield start
         start += step
```

Note that the standard library `range` does not accept any keyword arguments, thereby greatly simplifying its implementation.

Comment: yours first example is NOT equivalent to range in several cases and the stop condition will fail to step other that 1 in both examples

Comment: @Copperfield Thanks, fixed both.